# how to modify creation date in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I modify the date of file creation in Photoshop? I don't need any specific date, "today" will be okay. Is there any other meta-information stored in .psd files apart from what I can see in File->File info?

Edit:
It's not about the file creation time, .psd has its own date stored somewhere in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to change the modification/creation meta data. From the file-system's perspective and within the file's metadata.

### 1. Changing file-system modify/create date/time

### Windows

Depending on your OS, windows you can use a tool such as [File Cosmetic](http://www.nizuxsoft.com/filecosmetic/index.html) or [Finders Keepers](http://www.yadudigital.com/products/fk/touch_files.htm). See [this page](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/build-your-skills-learn-to-manipulate-file-time-stamps-in-windows/5034280) for more of them.

#### File Cosmetic

[image: ss file cosmetic]

#### Finders Keepers

[image: ss finders keepers]

### MacOSX

You can use the `touch` command ([man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch)), similar to other unixes.

#### For example:

```
% touch afile
% ls -l afile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 23 22:31 afile
% touch -m -t 198001010000 afile
% ls -l afile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan  1  1980 afile
```

### 2. Changing the modify/create date/time within file's metadata

### Commandline

You can use the commandline tool, `exiftool`, to manipulate metadata within various file types such as `TIFF` & `PSD`.

#### DateTimeOriginal before

```
% exiftool '-DateTimeOriginal' -f j.psd 
Date/Time Original              : 2009:05:31 08:32:08
```

#### Change the date time

```
% exiftool -overwrite_original "-DateTimeOriginal=1981:07:01 00:00:00" j.psd 
    1 image files updated
```

#### DateTimeOriginal after

```
% exiftool '-DateTimeOriginal' -f j.psd 
Date/Time Original              : 1981:07:01 00:00:00
```

**NOTE:** Further exiftool resources such as the [main site](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) & [forum](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/).

### GUI

You can use the GUI on Windows, [ExifToolGUI](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/), to make the same types of changes.

[image: ss of ExifToolGUI]

Comment: Similar to how camera JPG photos store EXIF tags about date picture was taken etc., PSD files too can contain *lots* of metadata in various formats, such as Photoshop-specific tags, IPTC tags, EXIF tags, XMP tags and so on. None of these have anything to do with file attributes such as date created/modified/accessed.

Comment: As per his query about "***any other*** meta-information", it seemed clear to me the date bit was also metadata he wanted to edit. But yeah, can probably update if he ever cares to return.

Comment: Well, I've changed the operating-system-type creation date, but it's still the same in Photoshop. I'd be very grateful if anyone could answer my question.

Comment: In case you're scared of the command line: there's exiftool GUI also.

Comment: Fasttone is also a great app and pretty much standard that can be used to edit all these properties.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop uses XMP format to store its metadata (like creation date). Here's a list of software that can modify it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform#XMP_support_and_acceptance

But I've found it easier to just duplicate all the layers to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You need a program to change the file date.  There is an app called "NewFileTime" that will change the date for you
[How to Change the Timestamp & Datestamp of your Files in Windows](http://www.freecong.com/2012/04/how-to-change-timestamp-datestamp-of.html)